# grep only returns help text

Tags: ubuntu, grep

Well, I am perplexed. I am working with an Ubuntu server and I type in

```
grep 'bash' *.sh
```

BUT

```
fgrep 'bash' *.sh
```

works like a champ.

```
which grep
```

and

```
which fgrep
```

both point to their respective executables in /bin. I am perplexed as to what I am doing wrong.

EXAMPLE output:

```
$ grep -F 'grounding' repl.clj
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input.
PATTERN is, by default, a basic regular expression (BRE).
Example: grep -i 'hello world' menu.h main.c

$ fgrep 'grounding' repl.clj 
(p/concepts-for-grounding-term imp1  "PERSON" "summary")
```

See? grep is failing but fgrep is working fine. That is why I am perplexed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want grep to work, I am just giving basic examples. It is only return help (usage) as if I did something wrong but no amount of rework seems to make a difference.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: Could it be you have an alias for grep? Does `$(which grep) 'bash' *.sh` work?

Comment: Ott, thanks, that says syntax error near unexpected token 'bash'

Comment: Ott - you got me thinking and I looked at my .bashrc file and sure enough it had corruption in it on the line that aliased grep. I fixed the line and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

grep, egrep, and fgrep have different behaviors. You don't show in your question what you're getting back from each of them, so it's hard to say more. The differences are discussed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-egrep-and-fgrep

The fact that they are the same executable on the filesystem isn't important, since it is likely that they change their behavior based on their own name. This is a minor optimization, to install and hardlink a single version of an executable to different names.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the grep man page:

```
   In  addition,  three  variant  programs  egrep,  fgrep  and  rgrep  are
   available.   egrep  is  the  same  as  grep -E.   fgrep  is the same as
   grep -F.  rgrep is the same as grep -r.  Direct  invocation  as  either
   egrep  or  fgrep  is  deprecated,  but  is provided to allow historical
   applications that rely on them to run unmodified.
```

fgrep is just a shortcut. So is egrep.

Comment: Yes, which is what is even more perplexing. Because fgrep pattern filename produces a result and grep -F pattern filename produces usage.

Answer (score 0):

> Ott - you got me thinking and I looked at my .bashrc file and sure
>   enough it had corruption in it on the line that aliased grep. I fixed
>   the line and now it works.

Learn from this lesson. Try to never ever alias or obfuscate the default commands like `ls` `grep`-- it will only come and bite you later on.

Instead of aliasing something like this:

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto --whoopssometypo'
```

Give your alias an original name:

```
alias grepc='grep --color=auto --whoopssomettypo'
```

This way, you aren't breaking default commands and you can quickly spot typos through some quick tests. If `grep` works, and `grepc` does not work, you can quickly tell that your problem is with `grepc` not grep.

If you had made your modification to an environment file which was shared by multiple admins, you could have caused substantial problems at your workplace.

I sometimes make one exception to this rule. Many Linux distros will alias a handful of destructive commands. Here is an example from a RHEL5 system:

```
# alias
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
```

The alias `rm -i` has saved me many times. However, relying on this alias is a bad habit, because sooner or later you'll be on a system where `rm` is not `rm -i` and you'll destroy files accidentally.